# FetchXml group by different values

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics, fetchxml

I want to count `Status Reason` on `Case` entity. But I don't know how to group by as shown bellow. I was looking around but couldn't find anything useful.

```
------------------------------------
ALIAS       | STATUS REASON
------------------------------------
Open        | New
------------------------------------
In progress | In Progress
------------------------------------
            | Problem solved
Closed      | No customer response
            | Merged
            | Canceled
------------------------------------
```

There are some more `Status Reason` values, which I don't want to count.

Is this even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309565(v=crm.6).aspx#groupby) it is in FetchXml only possible to *Group by*:

- linked entities
- year
- quarter
- month
- week
- day

When you cannot do without FetchXml (e.g. in reports on CRM OnLine) your only option is to get all data and do the grouping client side.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to retrieve the records using SSRS and perform the grouping in there. This would achieve both your requirements (i.e. grouping and exclusion of unwanted groups.)